# How to tell which local notification has been received? Objective - C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uilocalnotification

I have this piece of code which calls a different NSLog statement depending on which local notification has been received:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification{
    if (notification == automaticBackupNotification)
    {
        NSLog(@"Backup notification received.");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Did receive notification: %@, set for date:%@ .", notification.alertBody, notification.fireDate);
    }
}
```

And I use this method to schedule the notification in another class:

```
- (IBAction)automaticValueChanged {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (automaticSwitch.isOn){
        [defaults setValue:@"1" forKey:@"automatic"];
        //schedule notification
        //Set up the local notification
        appDelegate.automaticBackupNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        if(appDelegate.automaticBackupNotification){
            //Repeat the notification according to frequency
            if ([backupFrequencyLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Daily"]) {
                appDelegate.automaticBackupNotification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
            }
            if ([backupFrequencyLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Weekly"]) {
                appDelegate.automaticBackupNotification.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;
            }
            else {
                appDelegate.automaticBackupNotification.repeatInterval = NSMonthCalendarUnit;
            }

            //Set fire date to alert time
            NSCalendar *calendar = appDelegate.automaticBackupNotification.repeatCalendar;
            if (!calendar) {
                calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
            }

            NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
            components.day = 1;
            //NSDate *nextFireDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
            //appDelegate.automaticBackupNotification.fireDate = nextFireDate;
            appDelegate.automaticBackupNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:20.0];

            //Set time zone to default
            appDelegate.automaticBackupNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

            // schedule notification
            UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
            [app scheduleLocalNotification:appDelegate.automaticBackupNotification];

            NSLog(@"Backup Fire Date: %@", appDelegate.automaticBackupNotification.fireDate);
        }
    }
    else {
        [defaults setValue:@"0" forKey:@"automatic"];
        if(appDelegate.automaticBackupNotification){
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:appDelegate.automaticBackupNotification];
        }
    }

    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

However, when the application delegate receives the notification it fires the 'else' part of the conditional.  Is there any way I can tell between the different notifications?  Or am I doing something wrong?

Cheers,

Tysin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NSNotification object has property, which called userInfo. It is a NSDictionary, you can set some values where you create the notification and check for them where you receive it.

Answer (score 3):

Just try to set `userInfo` property of your `UILocalNotification`, like this,

```
NSDictionary *userDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"YOUROBJECT" forKey:@"TESTKEY"];
YOURNOTIFICATION.userInfo = userDict;
```

and when UILocalNotification fires this methods will be called,

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
     NSDictionary *dict = [notification userInfo];
     id obj = [dict objectForKey:@"TESTKEY"];
}
```

Based on `userInfo` you set at the time of setting `UILocalNotification`, You can find out which `notification` got called.

Answer (score 0):

I personnaly use the notification name to know which notification push or have been received

```
//add local observer
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(mathodCalled:) name:[NSSTring StringWithFormat :@"plop"] object:nil];

...

//push an event manually 
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:eventName object:[NSSTring StringWithFormat :@"plop"]];

...

- (void)methodCalled :(NSNotification*)aNotification{
    if([aNotification.name isEqualToString:@"plop"]){
        // do something
    }

}
```